# How do I open a new browser tab?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm working on this project and I have to open a new browser tab. Actually, I have to open a `target="_blank"` link without the link. I know is not right to interfere with the user preferences, but hey, this is the project requirements.

So, long story short, i have to replicate the `target="_blank"` behavior only with javascript.

Is this even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
window.open('http://www.example.com','_blank')
```

Comment: This opens a new window. Most browsers open tabs instead but the behavior is configurable. There's no guarantee that a new tab will be opened.

Answer (score -1):

```
var w = window.open();
$(w.document.body).html("Whatever or any ajax response ...")
```